# Converting rows to columns in R

Tags: r, transpose

I have a data like this

```
id , name , age, sex
1, sam, 22, m
2, rita, 34, f
3, robin, 32, f
4, josh, 21, m
```

i want to  convert the data to

```
id, name, age, m, f
1, sam, 22, 1,0
2, rita, 34, 0,1
3, robin, 32, 0,1
4, josh, 21, 1,0
```

Can i do this in R

other than using

```
dataset$m <- with(dataset, ifelse ((Type == "m"), 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
library(reshape2)
dataset1 <- dcast(dataset, ...~sex, value.var='sex', length)
dataset1
#  id  name age f m
#1  1   sam  22 0 1
#2  2  rita  34 1 0
#3  3 robin  32 1 0
#4  4  josh  21 0 1
```

#### Update

If there are duplicate rows for 'id/name/age' columns, we could create a sequence column ('ind') and then `dcast`

```
  datasetN$ind <- with(datasetN, ave(seq_along(id), id, name,
                 age, FUN=seq_along))
  subset(dcast(datasetN, ...~sex, value.var='sex', length), 
                                    select=-ind)
  #  id  name age f m
  #1  1   sam  22 0 1
  #2  2  rita  34 1 0
  #3  3 robin  32 1 0
  #4  3 robin  32 1 0
  #5  4  josh  21 0 1
```

#### Update2

Using 'train.csv' from [`here`](https://www.kaggle.com/c/restaurant-revenue-prediction/data?train.csv.zip)

```
train <- read.csv('train.csv')
train$ind <- with(train, ave(seq_along(City), City, FUN=seq_along))
res <- subset(dcast(train, ...~City, value.var='City', length),
       select=-ind)
dim(res)
#[1] 137  76
```

#### data

```
dataset <- structure(list(id = 1:4, name = c("sam", "rita", "robin",
"josh"
), age = c(22L, 34L, 32L, 21L), sex = c("m", "f", "f", "m")),
.Names = c("id", 
"name", "age", "sex"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

datasetN <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3), name = c("sam", 
"rita", 
"robin", "josh", "robin"), age = c(22, 34, 32, 21, 32), sex = c("m",
"f", "f", "m", "f")), .Names = c("id", "name", "age", "sex"), 
 row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: dcast returns the length right?. Is there any way to get 1. like binary

Comment: @user2728024  Do you have duplicate rows for the id, name, age combination?  If not, length will return a binary output

Comment: yeah i have duplicate records

Comment: @user2728024 I think we may need a sequence column for the groups, then

Comment: i am getting double the number of rows after executing the code.

Comment: that worked. But i am getting more number of rows in the output. My data size is 137 rows but i am getting 274 rows in the output after applying the function.

Comment: @user2728024  I created a dataset (`datasetN`) with duplicate rows and got the exact number of rows in the output.

Comment: any idea about the cause of repetition ? I am new to R

Comment: @user2728024  Is it possible for you to share the data in dropbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75153/discussion-between-user2728024-and-akrun).